# Do Riemann Integrable functions have same integral except at the middle thirds Cantor set?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f,g:[0,1]→ \mathbb{R}$ are Riemann Integrable and $f(x)=g(x)$ except on the middle-thirds Cantor set C. Prove that f and g have the same integral.

Any hints or any help to get started with this. I know the Cantor set has measure zero. Intuitively this seems true.

Also, if $f(x)=g(x)$, do they have the same integral except for x $\epsilon \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C$ has measure zero, given any $\varepsilon > 0$ you may cover $C$ by a union of intervals of total length at most $\varepsilon$. Call this union $I_\varepsilon$. Then

\begin{align}
\left | \int_0^1 f(x) dx - \int_0^1 g(x) dx \right | & \leq \int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)| dx \\ 
& = \int_{I_\varepsilon} |f(x)-g(x)| dx + \int_{[0,1] \setminus I_\varepsilon} |f(x)-g(x)| dx.
\end{align}

The second term is zero. How can you bound the first term? Hint: $f$ and $g$ are bounded.

Comment: How is the second term 0?

Comment: @Keith $f$ and $g$ are equal on $[0,1] \setminus C$. This is a superset of $[0,1] \setminus I_\varepsilon$, since $I_\varepsilon$ is a superset of $C$.